# Cast a struct of ints to an array of ints

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am using a library that has a function that takes an array of structs.  That struct and function has the following layout:

```
struct TwoInt32s
{
  int32_t a;
  int32_t b;
};

void write(struct TwoInt32s *buffer, int len);
```

My initial tests suggest that an array of such structs has the same memory layout as an array of `int32_t` so I can do something like this:

```
int32_t *buffer = malloc(2 * len * sizeof(int32_t));
/* fill in the buffer */
write((struct TwoInt32s*)buffer, len);
```

However I'm wondering if this is universally true or not.  Using an array of `int32_t` greatly simplifies my code.

EDIT: I forgot the sizeof

From what I read, C guarantees a few things about struct padding:

1. members will NOT be reordered
2. padding will only be added between members with different alignments or at the end of the struct
3. a pointer to a struct points to the same memory location as a pointer to its first member
4. each member is aligned in a manner appropriate for its type
5. there may be unnamed holes in the struct as necessary to achieve alignment

From this I can extrapolate that `a` and `b` have no padding between them.  However it's possible that the struct will have padding at the end.  I doubt this since it's word-aligned on both 32 and 64 bit systems.  Does anyone have additional information on this?

Comment: Be careful what is meant by 'len'. Is it the amount of memory allocated (probably not) or the number of structs in the array! Use sizeof() with malloc: malloc(2 * sizeof(TwoInt32s));

Comment: @James - yeah, I forgot the sizeof.  It's in my actual code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implementation is free to pad structs - there may be unused bytes in between `a` and `b`. It is guaranteed that the first member isn't offset from the beginning of the struct though.

Typically you manage such layout with a compiler-specific pragma, e.g:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct TwoInt32s
{
  int32_t a;
  int32_t b;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: I take from this that the answer is "no".  Unfortunately I have no control over the struct (it's from a library) so I can't pack it.

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi: Then you're out of luck, unless the lib already has this packed. If you don't need to be portable *and* your platform has this struct packed as you want, then you could cast. I'd static_assert on the layout (sizeof struct == 2*sizeof int32_t) in that case.

Comment: From what I've read, padding is only added between members if the members have different data alignments.  That means that in my case `a` and `b` should always be contiguous.  However padding can also be added at the end.  I'm not sure if there are any guarantees about that.  I'd guess that since this structure is word-aligned on 32 bit systems I can be guaranteed no-padding on 32 bit systems.

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi: See 9.2/12 "Implementation alignment requirements
might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other" - The 32-bit alignment on 32-bit systems isn't guaranteed, but I think you can be reasonably certain that it holds true in practice

Comment: @Erik - that's for C++.  I'm interested in C (C89, I suppose).  The spec is a bit vague and says that padding is implementation defined, but states some things that sound like I am (almost) guaranteed no padding in my case.  Specifically: 1) a pointer to a struct points to the same memory location as a pointer to its first member, 2) each member is aligned in a manner appropriate for its type, 3) there may be unamed holes in the struct *as necessary to achieve alignment*

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi: If you had a struct with two chars, and a cpu that didn't like non-32-bit-aligned access, then the implementation could align the chars on 32 bits. The same theory holds for ints, but IMO it's very much theoretic when applied to a 32-bit cpu with 32-bit ints. (btw, c++ POD is intended to be C89-compatible - I didn't have the C spec handy)

Comment: @Erik, yes my only concern would be strange CPUs but I don't think this is a realistic problem for me.  I also wonder if that would actually cause a problem, because if that were the case, then presumable a `char` would have size 4 and a char array would be indexed by word.

Answer (score 3):

malloc allocates bytes. Why did you choose "2*len" ?

You could simply use "sizeof":

```
int32_t *buffer = malloc(len * sizeof(TwoInt32s));
/* fill in the buffer */
write((struct TwoInt32s*)buffer, len);
```

and as Erik mentioned, it would be a good practice to pack the struct.

Comment: Yes, I hastily typed it up and forgot the sizeof.

Answer (score 2):

It's safest to not cast, but convert -- i.e., create a new array and fill it with the values found in the struct, then kill the struct.

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate structures but treat their members as a sort of virtual array:

```
struct TwoInt32s *buffer = malloc(len * sizeof *buffer);

#define BUFFER(i) (*((i)%2 ? &buffer[(i)/2].b : &buffer[(i)/2].a))

/* fill in the buffer, e.g. */
for (int i = 0; i < len * 2; i++)
    BUFFER(i) = i;
```

Unfortunately, neither GCC nor Clang currently "get" this code.

Comment: This is kind of a neat trick, but I specifically need the opposite of this.